# YOLOv8 prediction in Visual Basic

Tags: python, vb.net, yolo, python.net, yolov8

I am trying to run YOLOv8 prediction in visual basic however every time I run the predict about 35 instances of the program run in task manager (only one window is shown) but this makes it take forever. I have isolated the issue down to the line where I set results and invoke the prediction

My minimum reproducible code is here:

```vb
Imports System
Imports Python.Runtime

Public Class SimplePredict

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        ' Set the Python DLL path
        Runtime.PythonDLL = "-pathtodll-Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.dll"

        ' Initialize Python Engine
        PythonEngine.Initialize()

        ' Using the Python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)
        Using Py.GIL()
            ' Import necessary libraries
            Dim ultralytics = Py.Import("ultralytics")
            Dim YOLO = ultralytics.GetAttr("YOLO")

            ' Load model
            Dim modelName As String = "path-to-model.pt"
            Dim model = YOLO.Invoke(modelName.ToPython())

            ' Predict on an image
            Dim loadedImage As String = "-path-to-image"
            Dim predictMethod = model.GetAttr("predict")
            Dim results = predictMethod.Invoke(New PyObject() {loadedImage.ToPython()})

        End Using

        ' Shutdown the Python Engine
        PythonEngine.Shutdown()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I honestly have no clue what's going wrong but any help is appreciated

Comment: "*everytime i run the predict about 35 instances of the program run in task manager*" The library you're using leverages multiprocessing pretty extensively to more efficiently generate predictions, as the prediction itself is quite computationally expensive and would take a significantly longer amount of wall time without it. Can you elaborate on why you didn't expect this behavior? "*this makes it take forever*" Did this code not behave this way previously?

Comment: @esqew well if I run the script in python directly, this does not happen and I only get one output prediction. However here it is actually running the whole prediction 35 seperate times and showing the output 35 seperate times. The prediction directly in python takes less than a second, here as its doing it over and over again, takes over 5 minutes

Comment: Can you share a [mre] which shows the context of how you're invoking this code?

Comment: @esqew what I have posted in the question is it. I have it split across 2 files in my main implementation, but what ive posted is a minimal reproduction and gives the same error/has same issue. its just this one file in VS with the pythonnet nuget package installed and thats it